# How can we use postman global variable in the jenkins

Tags: jenkins, global-variables, postman, newman, postman-collection-runner

I am able to configure and execute postman/newman build with the jenkins with the use of postman collection's environment variable and its working fine.

The issue is when i try to use global variable file along with the main collection and environment variable. Its not working, jenkins does not identify global variable.

Comment: Can you supply the command that you're using please?

Comment: Yes..Please find below:      
   PATH of local system/npm/newman run                                                
 PATH of local system/Note.postman_collection.json
-e PATH of local system/Note.postman_environment.json 
--globals PATH of local system/Local_Build.postman_globals.json
 --insecure

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please use this command on MAC OS in shell command 
newman run Jenkins.postman_collection.json(Json file path) -e Staging.postman_environment.json(Environment variable path-json file) --globals Workspace.postman_globals.json(Global variable path-json file)